# Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])

Tags: r, function, dataframe, matrix, reduce

I am not sure why I am getting this error: `Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : unused argument (x[[i]])`. I am trying to convert row names to be the first column in multiple dataframes all at once like so:

```
ConvertRow2Col <- function(x){
  x$gene_names <- rownames(x) 
}

Reduce(ConvertRow2Col,(list(resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA)))
```

They look like this:

```
>head(resAKvA)
       log2FoldChange      padj
Gnai3     0.30991091 0.9997253
Cdc45    -0.22354949 0.9997253
H19       1.72882656 0.9997253
Scml2     3.83034861 0.9997253
Narf     -0.06818253 0.9997253
Cav2      2.08045461 0.9997253
```

And I want them to look like this:

```
gene_names log2FoldChange  padj
Gnai3     0.30991091 0.9997253
Cdc45    -0.22354949 0.9997253
H19       1.72882656 0.9997253
Scml2     3.83034861 0.9997253
Narf     -0.06818253 0.9997253
Cav2      2.08045461 0.9997253
```

I appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `tibble`'s `rownames_to_column` function across your data frames. Here is a step-by-step solution:

```
# import the necessary package
library(tibble)

# create a list of data frames
df_list <- list(resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA)

# apply the function to all data frames and update the list
df_list <- lapply(df_list, function(x) rownames_to_column(x, "gene_names"))

# access the individual data frames
df_list[[1]] # returns your first data frame (i.e. resAKvA)
```

Comment: This didn't seem to work as the gene names now are gone. They just got turned to numbers

Comment: @MoneebIrshadBajwa; I mistakenly used rowid instead of rownames, just edited the answer. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

A good alternative to your question might be to use `mapply` function and `rownames_to_column` from the `tibble` package.

```
mapply(function(x,y){tibble::rownames_to_column(x,y)},list(resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA),"gene_names",SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am still not understanding what the error means. I get the same error when I try something like this:`ConvertRow2Col=function(x)setDT(x, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]`

then `Reduce(ConvertRow2Col,(list(resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA)))`. I don't think I am understading functions properly.

Comment: OK but when I do: `mapply(function(x)setDT(resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA), keep.rownames = TRUE))[]` it doesn't work it just returns: `list()` to the console.

Comment: @MoneebIrshadBajwa Are you trying to convert  `resAKvA, resAKPvA, resAKTvA, resAKTPvA, resATPvA` to `data.table`? If so then you should use `Reduce` instead of `mapply`,